# When do I need to enable mbstring in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, wamp, mbstring

> mbstring extension provides enhanced support for Simplified Chinese,
>   Traditional Chinese, Korean, and Russian in addition to Japanese.

I tried displaying a Japanese character (which I copied from www.google.co.jp) on my PHP page and it displayed fine. Do I need to use mbstring when I'm displaying UTF-32 characters?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
    echo "भ";                  
    $s = strlen("भ");
    echo $s;
?>
```

How do I make the second line of code to work?

PS: I have changed PHP default charset to UTF-8.

Comment: All your questions would have a "It depends" answer. Stackoverflow also works best if you ask one question at a time. Start with [searching for your first one: "What is default encoding for PHP?"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=What+is+default+encoding+for+PHP%3F) - Some Q&A about that already exists.

Comment: You need to use mbstring if you intend to *process* any Unicode string. You don't need it if you just fetch and print blobs of bytes that just so happen to represent Unicode strings.

Comment: @Jon could you elaborate. I understand that unicode is not supported by PHP. But how does it render the japanese when it(php) is under the understanding that 1 byte = 1 character ?

Comment: @John: It does not. PHP passes on the bytes to the browser without realizing what they really mean, and it's the browser that knows how to render the text.

Comment: @Jon thax, one more doubt. See EDIT. Since PHP doesnt support unicode how do I do this?

Comment: `How do I make the second line of code to work?` Using `mb_strlen`, that's exactly mbstring's purpose.

Comment: great. But `strlen("भ");` prints 3 and `mb_strlen("भ");` also prints 3? It should have recognized it as 1 character now, right?

Comment: FWIW, भ is not Japanese. It's Devanagari 'bha' (used in various languages in India).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need the `mb_` string functions *in place of* the regular string functions, e.g. `mb_substr` instead of `substr`. If you don't use the regular string functions, there's no use for the `mb_` functions either.
- If you're just passing text through and PHP isn't *doing* anything with that text, there's no need for the `mb_` functions.
- To make the `mb_` functions work correctly, you'll have to tell them what encoding your text is in. They support many different encodings, without telling them which you're using their results will be incorrect. You can pass that encoding to each `mb_` function call, e.g. `mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')`, or you can set it once for all `mb_` functions using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for a comprehensive introduction.

Comment: I thought since I have set default charset to UTF-8 in php.ini i needn't provide 'UTF-8' in mb_ functions.

Comment: What option exactly did you set to UTF-8 in php.ini?

Comment: Have a look what the option is for: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset It is independent of and separate from the settings for the `mb_` functions.